# Renderscript throws assert exception "rsAssert failed: !mElements.size()"

Tags: android, image-processing, renderscript

I'm trying to set a grey effect on an image using `setGreyscale`. 
However, it throws the following exception:

> 01-29 17:10:51.360: E/RenderScript_jni(27312): No GC methods 
>   01-29 17:10:51.360: D/dalvikvm(27312): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.xxx.android/lib/libRSSupport.so 0x41f636a0 
>   01-29 17:10:51.384: D/dalvikvm(27312): Added shared lib /data/data/com.xxx.android/lib/libRSSupport.so 0x41f636a0 
>   01-29 17:10:51.384: D/dalvikvm(27312): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.xxx.android/lib/libRSSupport.so 0x41f636a0, skipping init 
>   01-29 17:10:51.391: D/dalvikvm(27312): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.xxx.android/lib/librsjni.so 0x41f636a0 
>   01-29 17:10:51.391: D/dalvikvm(27312): Added shared lib /data/data/com.xxx.android/lib/librsjni.so 0x41f636a0 
>   01-28 16:48:38.340: E/RenderScript(19242): rsAssert failed: !mElements.size(), in frameworks/rs/rsElement.cpp at 369

Here is the code:

```
import android.support.v8.renderscript.*;

private synchronized void setGreyScale(Bitmap image){
    Allocation input;
    Allocation output;
    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(mContext);
    ScriptIntrinsicColorMatrix scriptColor = ScriptIntrinsicColorMatrix.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, image, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
    output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.getType());
    scriptColor.setGreyscale();
    scriptColor.forEach(input, output);
    output.copyTo(image);                         
    rs.destroy();
}
```

Comment: that's not the actual crash, that's a side effect of other things. can you post your full logcat?

Comment: @TimMurray You were right, this is not the cause for the crash. I've updated the post and added more logcat messages. I think it may be related to build configurations. WDYT? thank you!

Comment: what device are you running on? there's still not anything I obviously think is an exception. do you see a native stack trace or a Java stack trace anywhere?

Comment: I'm running on Samsung S3. I've added sdk.buildtools=18.1.0 to my project.propeties and it works now, the exception still happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after setting `sdk.buildtools` to version `18.1.0`.
Previously, the version was `19.0.0`.

Here is my current `project.properties`:

> target=android-19
>   renderscript.target=18
>   renderscript.support.mode=true
>   sdk.buildtools=18.1.0

The assert exception still occurs so it's not related to the actual failure.